# What is the use of PreferredSize widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter, and I see there are few widgets for the layout design such as SizedBox and Container.
There is one widget which is **PreferredSize** Widget that I don't know and cannot find any example about it. 
What makes it different from other widgets such as container and SizedBox which can set height and width?.
Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html

Any widget with a `PreferredSize` can appear at the bottom of an `AppBar`.

You can use `PreferredSize` to setting up your `AppBar` Size.

```
class MyApp1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Example',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0), // here the desired height
                child: AppBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Example"),
                )
            ),

        )
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question is, what is the difference between using a sized box of a certain size or using preferred size

Comment: Theoretically, it will only constrain the size if the child's size is unbound. Which lifts the question: what's the difference between using `PreferredSize` and `ConstrainedBox`? No one knows.

Answer (score 18):

> Preferred Size is a custom widget lets you allow to design your custom appbar for you with the same height, width, elevation and feel similar to Appbar.
>
> Sometimes you want to create tabs or more effective design for your appbar then you can create a customChild for your appBar with the help of PreferredSizeWidget.

For Ex : If you want to create a custom appbar with backgradient

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color gradientStartColor = Color(0xff11998e);
Color gradientEndColor = Color(0xff0575E6);

class PreferredSizeApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PreferredSizeAppState createState() => _PreferredSizeAppState();
}

class _PreferredSizeAppState extends State<PreferredSizeApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size(double.infinity, kToolbarHeight),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                  color: gradientStartColor,
                  offset: Offset(1.0, 6.0),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                ),
                BoxShadow(
                  color: gradientEndColor,
                  offset: Offset(1.0, 6.0),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                ),
              ],
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    gradientStartColor,
                    gradientEndColor
                  ],
                  begin: const FractionalOffset(0.2, 0.2),
                  end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.0),
                  stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
            ),
            child: Center(child: Text("Appbar With Gradient",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 25.0),)),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the great way to use PreferredSizeWidget. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create your own custom prefered size widget all you need to do is to implement `PreferredSizeWidget` interface in your widget.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); // Your custom widget implementation.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use it when you're using a container in `SliverAppBar()`

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  pinned: true,
  snap: true,
  floating: true,
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    child: Container(),
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
  )),
```

Answer (score 2):

`PreferredSize` is a wrapper around the `PreferredSizeWidget` which you can use to create a custom `AppBar`.

This is how you will extend a `PreferredSize` class:

```dart
class FooBar extends PreferredSize {
  final String data;
  FooBar(this.data);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RockingText(data); // Your custom widget implementation. 
  }
}
```

and this is how you use it:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: FooBar('My App bar'),
)
```