# What is PreferredSize after all?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand that it is used to adjust AppBar, but what is PreferredSize after all? 
[What is the use of PreferredSize widget in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177759/what-is-the-use-of-preferredsize-widget-in-flutter)

The following text is found in the official documents, but I do not understand what it means.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html

> It just advertises a preferred size which can be used by the parent.

The explanation in the official documentation is also limited to the AppBar, which I could not understand further.

I wrote the following code as a test, but the height of the green container was spread across the entire screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const _MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size this widget would prefer if it were otherwise unconstrained.
In many cases it's only necessary to define one preferred dimension.
For example the [Scaffold] only depends on its app bar's preferred
height. In that case implementations of this method can just return
`Size.fromHeight(myAppBarHeight)`.