# AppBar on all Screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

I think I have a simple question but I don't know why its not work

Simple:
**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: const Welcome(),
    );
  }
}
```

Second file:
**welcome.dart**

```
  class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  const Welcome({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarNav(
        title: 'JobFinder',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AppBar file:
**appbar.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarNav extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const AppBarNav({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    );
  }
}
```

Debbuger say:
The argument type 'AppBarNav' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

Why?

Do you know why the debugger tells me that I can't use AppBar in the Welcome.dart file?
I know it's probably simple but I can't find a solution to it.

Generally I want to place an appBar on every screen (same Appbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
class AppBarNav extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  const AppBarNav({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
 Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight); 
}
```

By implementing the `PreferredSizeWidget` interface, you provide information to the framework about how much vertical space your widget should occupy in the app bar, allowing for proper layout and positioning of other widgets within the app bar.

In `AppBarNav`, implemented the `PreferredSizeWidget` interface because we want to customize the app bar's behavior, specifically its preferred size.

`Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);`, is a getter method that defines the preferred size of a widget.

`Size get preferredSize:` This line defines a getter method named `preferredSize` that returns a `Size` object.

`Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)`: This part creates a `Size` object with the height specified by `kToolbarHeight`. `kToolbarHeight` is typically a constant defined in Flutter (often set to 56.0 in logical pixels), representing the standard height of a toolbar or app bar in a Flutter app.

Answer (score 4):

the argument `appBar` needs to be directly an `AppBar`. You are giving it an `AppBarNav` which is not an `AppBar` even if it only consists of one.

Technically it doesn't need to be an `AppBar` but a `PreferredSizeWidget` which an `AppBar` implements. So alternatively you could also let your `AppBarNav` implement `PreferredSizeWidget` like this

```
class AppBarNav extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  const AppBarNav({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  Size get preferredSize => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

But then you need to provide an implementation for `preferredSize` also

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarNav extends AppBar {
  final String title;
  const AppBarNav({super.key,String? title}) : super(title : title ?? '');

}
```

Or maybe this one :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppBarNav extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const AppBarNav({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[Colors.blue, Colors.pink],
            ),
          ),
          child: const Text(title),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177759/what-is-the-use-of-preferredsize-widget-in-flutter#:%7E:text=Preferred%20Size%20is%20a%20custom,and%20feel%20similar%20to%20Appbar.)  and [this documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) example.